# Passing Collections and list through query string in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building a .Net project using C#.

Here am finding some difficulties to pass list of object through querystring

lets have a look into code:

```
 List<string> Advantages = new List<string>();

     protected void AddAdvBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
            Advantages.add(textbox1.text);
            Advantages.add(textbox2.text);
            Advantages.add(textbox3.text);
            //so on                       
     }
```

Fine, I am using querystring to pass advantages object like below

```
Response.Redirect("~/example.aspx?listObj=" + Advantages);
```

Until now everything works fine. 
after redirected to `example.aspx`, list is not returning values, instead it's returning `system.collection` something getting.

I have written code to get querystring object below like this:

```
 string str = Request.QueryString["AdvantagesList"];
```

Comment: You might wanna change string str to List or array since you are redirecting an entire List.

Comment: If you really need to pass a list from one page to the other you might want to use the `Session` instead.

Comment: convert it to string

Comment: how do i convert request.querystring[""] to list .i have used like this list<string> adv=request.querystring[""].tolist()  giving error

Comment: You should use `Session` variable for this as mentioned by Tim, but for some reason if you wish to pass it in query string, then you need to send data as a single string, so use `String.Join` & on other page retrieve it via `String.Split` method. But, please note this is not a recommended approach.